# Window Maximization Restraint?

Tags: window

I'm not sure if this has been asked, and I'm not even sure what to call it. What I'm trying to do is make Windows look as close to a Mac as possible, I'm wondering if there is a program that when you hit maximize it restrains the Windows from going all the way to the bottom and covering the dock.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve? As far as I can see, what you've described so far is already the default behaviour in Windows - maximised programs do not extend all the way to the bottom and cover up the taskbar.

Comment: sorry, i realize i was extremely vague. i was trying to make it so that when i click the maximize button on my browser it would not cover a rocket dock. my task bar is on the top of my screen, not the bottom. I found a program to do this, but thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Windows? XP had an option in taskbar properties to always **Keep the taskbar on top of other Windows**:

[image]

However this option is no longer present in Windows 7 (not sure about Vista). In Win7 check that the taskbar is not set to auto-hide. Also, if a full-screen app hides the taskbar, see if there's any way to not run it full-screen.

Comment: sorry its windows 7 and actually i found a program called adjustworkarea, that is run by a cmd to reset the usable desktop work area!

Answer (score 0):

So I actually found the program I needed. So to clarify, I have my taskbar on the top of my screen, and a rocketdock on the bottom, to look like a Mac. and i wanted it so that when i hit maximize it would stop at the top of the dock like a mac. If you look for a program called [AdjustWorkArea](http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=27075), its just what you need! The instructions are EXTREMELY vague though. This is what my computer now looks like:

[image: my desktop]

So you see the browser does not go to the bottom of the screen, just like a Mac!